# Set MS Word 2010 Document Name from COM Addin

Tags: com, ms-word, add-in, document

I'm searching for a way to preset the proposed filename in the `SaveAs` dialog of Ms Word 2010 from an COM AddIn. (Additionally I'd like to set also the default store path, but that is just secondary.)

I'm using the default `SaveAs` `commandButton` of the word, because the file should be stored in a SharePoint-Environment and the .Net `SaveFileDialog` doesn't support that. Code I'm using:

```
    var match = Application.CommandBars.FindControl(
                MsoControlType.msoControlButton, 748, null, null);
    match.Execute();
```

Things I've tried:

- The `Application.Document.Name` and `FullName` properties only provide getters, so those are not available to set (why, I can't imagine).
- Searching for the default `FileName` which can be set in the Word Settings (so set it to some value and then revert it later on)
- Checked if there are other API operations available to set the document name.
- A very dirty solution would be to store the document to a temp dir with the `Document.SaveAs("fileName.doc")` operation, so when executing the `SaveAs` button the name is already set.

Any ideas or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, this worked for me. Using VS2010 & Office 2010

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document objWordDocument;
object objMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
objWordDocument = objWordApplication.Documents.Add(ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing);
objWordDocument.Activate();
objWordDocument.ActiveWindow.Caption = "CallMeWhatYouWill";
```